# How to find the layout width and height while the activity is loading?

Tags: android, layout, height, width

In my app,I should find width and height of a frame layout  at the time of activity is loading.When i tried this,i am getting null pointer exception displaying width and height must be greater than zero.Please help me how to find width and height of frame layout in my xml.Thanks in advance.

my main Activity is

```
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.graphics.Bitmap;
  import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
   import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.FrameLayout;
  import android.widget.ImageView;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ImageView  image;
FrameLayout frame;
  int width,height;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    frame=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame);


    frame.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener( 
            new OnGlobalLayoutListener(){
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {                   
                    width=frame.getWidth();
                    height = frame.getHeight(); 

                    frame.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener( this );                               
                }

        });



    Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
      Bitmap scaled=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true);
    image.setImageBitmap(scaled);
    image.setOnTouchListener(new myTouchListener());

       }
       }
```

and my main xml is

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@android:color/black"
   android:orientation="vertical" 
   android:weightSum="3"
   >  
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:id="@+id/top_linear"
    android:layout_weight="1"
   >
  </LinearLayout>

   <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="380dp"
    android:id="@+id/frame" 
     >
     <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:scaleType="matrix"
     />    
  </FrameLayout>    
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="@android:color/black"
     android:id="@+id/bottom_linear">

   </LinearLayout>


   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is a delicate issue in Android. One way of dealing with this issue is to implement your own custom layout class and in this class to override onLayout and onMeasure methods. There is a good deal of information in Android docs about how these methods do function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your code for the Bitmap handling into the block of the ViewTreeObeserver. Before this code block will be executed the width and height are 0.

```
frame.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener( 
        new OnGlobalLayoutListener(){
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {                   
                width=frame.getWidth();
                height = frame.getHeight(); 

                Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                Bitmap scaled=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true);
                image.setImageBitmap(scaled);
                image.setOnTouchListener(new myTouchListener());

                frame.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener( this );                               
            }

    });
```

Comment: Oh thanks yaar.Just a small thing.I have spent so much of time for this.thanks for your reply.It has worked.

Answer (score -1):

getWidth() and getHeight() methods return 0 when layouts width and height are set like match_parent and wrap_content. dimensions are not measured.

The right methods to access to get measured dimensions are getMeasuredWidth() and getMeasuredHeight().

The Correct way:

```
FrameLayout frmlayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.svtest);
ViewTreeObserver vto = frmlayout.getViewTreeObserver(); 
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onGlobalLayout() { 
        scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this); 
        int width  = frmlayout.getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = frmlayout.getMeasuredHeight(); 

    } 
});
```

Comment: thanks yaar for your reply.Steve Benett answer worked for me.